# what is the usage of \& and $expr->()

Tags: perl

```
sub reduce(&@) {

    my $expr = \&{shift @ARG};

    my $result = shift @ARG;
    while (scalar @ARG > 0) {
        our $a = $result;
        our $b = shift @ARG;
        $result = $expr->();
    }

    return $result;
}
```

I cannot really understand some grammar in this code. Anyone can explain to me? like `\&` and `$result = $expr->()`

Comment: I'm not a perl guy, but I'm pretty sure `$expr` is a [subroutine reference](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/perl/advprog/ch04_01.htm). I believe `\&{shift @ARG}` will convert the first argument to a subroutine reference, and `$expr->()` will call that subroutine. Note that it makes values `$a` and `$b` available to the subroutine as globals.

Answer (score 10):

`\&name` returns a reference to the subroutine named `name`.

`$code_ref->()` calls the subroutine referenced by `$code_ref`.

```
$ perl -e'
    sub f { CORE::say "Hi" }
    my $code_ref = \&f;
    $code_ref->();
'
Hi
```

---

In your case, `shift @ARG` returns a subroutine reference. `\&{ $code_ref }` simply returns the code ref. As such,

```
my $expr = \&{shift @ARG};
```

could have been written as

```
my $expr = shift @ARG;
```

---

Note that `reduce`'s prototype allows it to be called as

```
reduce { ... } ...
```

but what is actually executed is

```
reduce( sub { ... }, ... )
```

---

Note that this version of `reduce` is buggy. You should use the one provided by [List::Util](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?List::Util).

- `local $a` and `local $b` should have been used to avoid clobbering the values its caller might have in `$a` and `$b`.
- This version of `reduce` expects its callback to have been compiled in the same package as `reduce` itself. Otherwise, the callback sub won't be able to simply use `$a` and `$b`.
- Declaring the variables using `our` is actually completely useless in this version case since `$a` and `$b` are exempt from `use strict;` checks, and the undeclared use of `$a` and `$b` would access the very same package variables.

Comment: how about our before variables?

Comment: They create lexically-scoped aliases to the package variables `$a` and `$b`. That means that if the current package is `Foo`, it creates an alias called `$a` for the variable `$Foo::a`. Changing one will change the other. These variables will be accessed by the referenced subroutine. If `my $a` and `my $b` would have been used, these would create variables that the referenced subroutine couldn't see.

Answer (score 1):

Having a look some [List::Util::reduce()](http://perldoc.perl.org/List/Util.html#%24result-%3D-reduce-%7B-BLOCK-%7D-%40list) examples will probably help.

Let's take the first one:

```
$foo = reduce { $a > $b ? $a : $b } 1..10;
```

So `reduce` takes a `BLOCK` followed by a LIST, which the function signature declares: `sub reduce(&@) {`.  The block in our case is the statement `$a > $b ? $a : $b`, while the list is `1..10`.  From the docs:

> Reduces @list by calling "BLOCK" in a scalar context multiple times,
>   setting $a and $b each time. The first call will be with $a and $b set to
>   the first two elements of the list, subsequent calls will be done by
>   setting $a to the result of the previous call and $b to the next element
>   in the list.
>
> Returns the result of the last call to the "BLOCK". If @list is empty then
>      "undef" is returned. If @list only contains one element then that element
>      is returned and "BLOCK" is not executed.

And now to an annotated version of the code:

```
$foo = reduce { $a > $b ? $a : $b } 1..10;  # $foo will be set to 10

sub reduce(&@) {
    # reduce() takes a BLOCK followed by a LIST
    my $expr = \&{shift @ARG};
    # $expr is now a subroutine reference, i.e.
    # $expr = sub { $a > $b ? $a : $b };

    # Start by setting $result to the first item in the list, 1
    my $result = shift @ARG;

    # While there are more items in the list...
    while (scalar @ARG > 0) {
        # Set $a to the current result
        our $a = $result;

        # Set $b to the next item in the list
        our $b = shift @ARG;

        # Set $result to the result of $a > $b ? $a : $b
        $result = $expr->();
    }

    # List has now been reduced by the operation $a > $b ? $a : $b
    return $result;
}
```